# magento 2.1 checkout tab "shipping" missing

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping, magento-2.1

I have two sites: local under windows/xampp and remote server under linux with magento 2.1 updated.
Local site has two tabs at checkout - "Shipping" and "Rewiew and payment"

[image]

And server site has only one - "Rewiew and payment"

[image]

I need to get back "Shipping" tab because I have some functionality there and my shipping methods are invisible.

Please, help to understand **what might be different?** The thing is I don't know whether this is a magento core changes that came with version 2.1 or admin panel settings. Checkout and shipping settings in admin seems to be similar. I flushed magento cache, cleaned browser cache, upgraded system and static resources, etc.

Comment: What type of products are you adding to your cart ? Adding only virtual/downloadable products won't display the shipping step

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism . Why it also does not show for configurable products too?

Comment: It shows for configurable products but not for virtual/downloadable

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, I just set "this item hasn't weight" so this made product "downloadable" automatically. Now this tab appeared. Thanx!

Comment: I've added it as answer ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism . You can see screenshot @ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFQl9nLWZuampSM1U/view?usp=drivesdk  . This is my configurable product and it still does not show shipping option on checkout. Let me know if something needs to configure for the same.

Comment: @RJ07 it can be something to do with your shipping method. As White Imp said using shipping methods that use weight can be the cause of the problem

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Yes you were right. Due to missing weight configuration in my simple product it was not showing up. Now its working fine. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem tend to appear when you add to cart virtual and/or downloadable products.

Adding simple/configurable products should fix the issue.

Also it is highly possible that it is caused by the configured shipping methods and the weight of your products.

Comment: In my case I set "This product has no weight" and then add it to cart.

Answer (score 0):

please add weight of product . if you remove then the problem happen as virtual product